# How to create a friendly URL with two or more arguments using mod rewrite / htaccess?

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Mod rewrite novice here. I want to pass two URL parameters in the URL, but in a more friendlier format. If user passes, "example.com/blah123/sys", I should be able to extract the MySQL record "blah123" and the mode type "sys", in this case. Here's the example:

URL:

```
example.com/blah123/sys
```

In the .htaccess, I have:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ index.php?id=$1
```

The above works if the URL passed is: "example.com/blah123", but not "example.com/blah123/sys".

I tried the following, but it is not working:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$/?$ index.php?id=$1?mode=$1
```

I need to extract the "mode" type passed in the second argument. So, if the user enters "example.com/blah123/sys", I should be able to get the value "sys" from the URL. How can I do that? I want to use PHP, MySql, .htacess.

UPDATE:
My current .htaccess:

```
# Use PHP 5.3
AddType application/x-httpd-php53 .php 
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ index.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/?$ index.php?id=$1&mode=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your regex is wrong. You cannot have `$` following another `$` in an input since `$` denotes end of text.

This rule should work:

```
RewriteEngine On

# new rule to handle example.com/blah123/sys
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/(\w+)/?$ /index.php?id=$1&mode=$2 [L,QSA]

# your existing rule to handle example.com/blah123
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/?$ /index.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: id=$1?mode=$1 are you sure, that here should be a question mark as a delimiter between params? Seems, that PO made an error.

Comment: That 2'nd `?` should be a `&`

Comment: @AndreasBjørn: Thanks man, once again sorry for the bad copy/paste from question.

Comment: @anubhava Thank you for your response. Now, the "example.com/blah123/sys" seems to work, but not "example.com/blah123". The problem is the user can enter both URL types,i.e either "example.com/blah123/sys" OR "example.com/blah123". Is there a way I can have both the situations work?

Comment: @Gandalf: Are you sure `"example.com/blah123"` doesn't work. I tried both URIs with these rules and both worked fine. You may have some other conflicting rule. Can you post your existing .htaccess in question.

Comment: @anubhava I have added it to the original question. Using "example.com/blah123" is taking me to the 404 error pages.

Comment: I tried, but it is now going to 404 for both cases (i.e with both 1 or 2 arguments). Please let me know if you have any other suggestions.

Comment: @anubhava Just wanted your help again. I noticed that "example.com/blah123" works, but "example.com/blah123/" doesn't. Is there a way it can be little more fool-proof so that even if there is a "/" at the end of the URL, it should work? Same goes with "example.com/blah123/sys/"

Comment: Trailing slash should work because I have /?$ in my rule which makes last slash optional.