# how to rewrite Url and make them static for easy access

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

i have a ecommerce site and want to rewrite url using .htaccess in wordpress.
here is exmple URL that want to change

http://www.domain.com/page_id=55&catid=66

into

http://www.domain.com/camera

how is this possible..?

Comment: Did you do one search at all? There are litterally hundreds of examples for such a basic rewrite. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20277428/how-to-create-a-friendly-url-with-two-or-more-arguments-using-mod-rewrite-htac

Comment: yh i have search but could not find any helpful example ..

Comment: It took me 30 seconds to find that link. :) The answer should help you.

Comment: but i want the specific rewrite that easy allow me to create this type of url

Comment: The link above in the fist comment shows you how to right it. Just change out your query string parameters in the rewrite rule. Can't get any easier.

Comment: ok i will try to solve this issue